# iPhone display width

Tags: iphone, html, css, mobile

Its my understanding that the display width for Safari on an iphone is 640px. I have built a website at 640px width, but when i look at it on my iPhone 4, it only takes up 2/3 of the screen. Any ideas?

Comment: please add an example - upload it to the web?

Comment: well there is a div with everything in like so: <div id="container">...</div> and it has a width set to 640px

Comment: is the other 1/3 white space?

Comment: I meant a working example that shows your problem that can be run on an iphone.

Answer (score 2):

You may need to specify the ViewPort to ensure Safari does not resize/scale the page.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0,maximum-scale=1.0,user-scalable=no" />
```